# C#: simplify generics declaration

Tags: c#, generics

I'm working with generics in C#, and I feel like I have redundant information in my type specifications.

I have an interface named `IParameterizedViewModel`, which is generic on a parameter type. I also have another abstract class (android activity), which uses that kind of ViewModel.

```
public interface IParameterizedViewModel<TParameter> : IBaseViewModel
{
}

abstract class BaseActivity<TViewModel, TParameter> : BaseActivity<TViewModel>
    where TViewModel : IParameterizedViewModel<TParameter>
{
    // Somewhere in here, we use the TParameter type,
    // so it's important to know the type.
}
```

You can see here that the `BaseActivity` has a generic `IParameterizedViewModel` type. I also have types which fill the generic slots for these two:

```
public interface IDetailsViewModel : IParameterizedViewModel<Details>
{
}

class DetailsActivity : BaseActivity<IDetailsViewModel, Details>
{
}
```

Now here's the thing: this last definition, `DetailsActivity` looks redundant as to the parameter type `Details`, since that type is also included in the `IDetailsViewModel`

Is there a way I could get away with removing the `Details` type, since it is already specified in the `IDetailsViewModel` type?

```
class DetailsActivity : BaseActivity<IDetailsViewModel>
{
}
```

Comment: Is it important for `DetailsActivity` to know you are using `IDetailsViewModel`? Or would `IParameterizedViewModel<Details>` be sufficient? Unfortunately, your question lacks a good [mcve], so it's not clear all of the constraints that apply to your scenario.

Comment: (I'm also sure you're not the first person to ask how to avoid specifying the same generic type twice...this does come up from time to time. So your time would be well-spent searching Stack Overflow for the question that yours is a duplicate of and which almost certainly exists.)

Comment: Yeah, I did search SO for similar questions. I found a few questions close, but none exactly the same. Also yes, `DetailsActivity` must know it is using an `IDetailsViewModel`. I'll try and post a more complete example later. Feel free to point out what's missing exactly, as this looks complete to me.